# Cannot access web service from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Several months ago, I wrote an application in VB.Net that accesses a Cold Fusion web service.  The web service (which is sitting on a CF Server on the cloud) was set up as a Web Reference in my VB.Net project.  When I execute the built application on a system running Windows Server 2003, it has no problem whatever consuming this web service.

Fast forward to today.  I am attempting to consume this web service on an adjacent Win7 computer using the same network/connection, and everytime I run the application either in the VS2010 IDE or as the built application, it gives me the error: "The underlying connection was closed:  The connection was closed unexpectedly."

I have made no changes to either the web service or VB.Net code.

What would be causing such an error?

Here is my VB.NET code that consumes the service:

```
 Public Function ConnectedToTheInternet() As Boolean
    Dim myservice = New TestService.testservicecfc()

    Try
        myservice.echoString("hello")
        ConnectedToTheInternet = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        ConnectedToTheInternet = False
    End Try

End Function
```

and here is my web service code:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction name="echoString" returnType="string" output="no" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="input" type="string">
        <cfreturn #arguments.input#>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponenet>
```

I have tried disabling my Windows Firewall, but this had no effect.

Comment: Instead of declaring and instantiating a web service variable in each method that uses it, I created one global web service variable which is instantiated when my application is first executed.  This seems to have solved the problem.  Any other suggestions are still welcome.

Comment: OK.  I lied.  This still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, however I would try and add some code permissions, look up role-based security and make sure that your application has all the permissions in the code to access the server.

use the **GenericIdentity** and the **GenericPricipal** keywords.

here is some example code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Security.Principal 
Imports System.Threading

Public Shared Sub Main()
'Hard coded username
Dim strUsername As String = "admin"

'Create GenericIdentity
Dim gidMyID as New GenericIdentity(strUsername)
Dim strMyRole As String = "Some Role"

'Create GenericPrincipal
Dim gplMyPrincipal As New GenericPrincipal(MyIdentity, MyRoles)

'Store the principal for later use
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = gplMyPrincapal 

End Sub
```

you can set this so that it see you as an admin then all you need to do is tell your server that the role you defined is allowed to access the web service.

the last bit of code is to call the web service if you have been authenticated

```
if(String.Compare(gplMyPrincapal, "DOMAIN\Admin", True) = 0) Then
    'enter code here
Else
    Msgbox("Cannot Connect", "Error")
End If
```

not sure if this will help but its worth a go